# How to submit 2 python (pyspark) scripts to the same spark session in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running spark 3.0 on 1 ec2 instance in a local mode.
I would like to be able to run multiple python scripts in parallel [2 jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfbJa.png)
today, in order to provide access to spark session I use -

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name) \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

but then on the EC2 i see 2 spark processes running, opening 2 UIs (4040/4041 ports) and most importantly the 2 scripts cannot use the spark.catalog running on hive metastore derby.

how can this 2 jobs share the same spark session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible to use HiveDerbyServerMode, the instructions in the link are very clear and works

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveDerbyServerMode